# Can Powerbi count multiple occurrences of a specific text within a cell?

Tags: count, powerbi, dax

What i am trying to find out is, for example let's take as an example the following table:

```
 | Col 1 | Col 2   |
 |-------|---------|
 | ab    | 1       |
 | ab ab | 2       |
 | ac    | 1       |
 | ae    | 1       |
 | ae ae | 2       |
 | af    | 1       |
```

So basically if there are two occurrences of the same item in the cell, I want to display 2 in the next column. If there are 3, then 3 and so on. The thing is that I am looking for specific strings most of the time. Its a text and number string.

Is this doable in Power BI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to count the number of occurrences of the first non-space characters that occur before the first separating space, you can do the following:

```
Col 2 = 
VAR Trimmed = TRIM(Table2[Col 1])
VAR FirstSpace = SEARCH(" ", Trimmed, 1, LEN(Trimmed) + 1)
VAR FirstString = LEFT(Trimmed, FirstSpace - 1)
RETURN DIVIDE(
           LEN(Trimmed) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Trimmed, FirstString, "")),
           FirstSpace - 1
       )
```

---

Let's go through an example to see how this works. Suppose we have a string " abc abc abc ".

The `TRIM` function removes any extraneous spaces at the beginning an end, so `Trimmed` = "abc abc abc".

The `FirstSpace` searches for the first space in `Trimmed`. In this case, `FirstSpace` = 4. (If there is no first space, then we define `FirstSpace` to be the length of `Trimmed` + 1 so the next part works correctly.)

The `FirstString` uses `FirstSpace` to find the first chunk. In this case, `FirstString` = "abc".

Finally, we use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace each `FirstString` with an empty string (leaving only the middle spaces) and look at how that changes the length of `Trimmed`. We know `LEN(Trimmed)` = 11 and `LEN("  ")` = 2, so the difference is the 9 characters we removed by substitution. We know that the 9 characters are n copies of `FirstString`, "abc" and we know the length of `FirstString` is `FirstSpace` - 1 = 3.

Thus we can solve 3n = 9 for n to get n = 9/3 = 3, the count of the "abc" substrings.

Comment: This is quite interesting and solves half of my problem. However, the issue becomes visible when my strings are listed like `"ARL-1672 - ARL-1685"` or `"ARL-1694 ARL-8854"`. I was wondering if i can count those results by key substrings like in my case, the `"ARL"` text. I'm thinking that would solve the issue by counting the nr of `"ARL"` occurrences found in the cell

Comment: Yeah, for that you could use "-" instead of " " and you'd get the count of "ARL" substrings.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much sir.